# ROS Answers SE migration: Run a node

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have installed and compiled secessfully the follwing packages : amcl_listener ,pow_analyzer, cereal_port, gps_umd and scan_tools. I have only one launch file and all works perfect. But would like to run the each node. So I need a launch file for each package to run the package node? for example how to run the scan tools node?Any help?
And i tried to edit some lauch file code and was not able to do that, whats wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38878/run-a-node/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-16**:
You mean the correct package parameters or?And remappings of what?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
The node's parameters and topic remappings. I'd advise to read some basic tutorials that explain this better.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-16**:
So better to run a launch file for very node yes?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
It depends. If you just want to run a node and you don't need to change much, rosrun is absolutely fine. roslaunch is needed for a single node if there are parameters to change or topic remappings to make that you don't want to give manually all the time.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
If you want to run something singly that warrants a launch file you can also make single launch files out of the one you use.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-16**:
ok. So if I want run a luanch file than have to create the package and everything , yes? I mean I have installed and comiled the packages but have only one lanch file for all.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
You can make a launch file for a single node or just use rosrun if you don't need to set parameters or remap topics. If you do, the advantage of the launch file is that you don't have to give all those settings on the cmd line.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-16**:
Ok. So the basic tutorials explain hot to make tne lauch file yes? The coomand for making a lauch file also can be find there?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-16**:
The basic tutorials describe parameters and topics, so you actually know what you want to do. Documentation for roslaunch can be found on it's wiki site: http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to run individual node from command line using following command:

```
rosrun <package-name> <binary-name-in-package-bin>
```

http://ros.org/wiki/rosrun

It is advisable to use launch file as it is easier to setup various parameters. Launch files avoids a lot of overhead of typing same commands on command line.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just use rosrun to run single nodes. You only need to make sure that the correct parameters are set on the server and use remappings if needed.

The basic ROS tutorials explain this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1